# Mock method inside thread class

Tags: php, pthreads, codeception

i'm tring to mock a method inside a class that extens Threaded

```
class Tclass  extends \Threaded
{
    public function __construct( $name )
    {
         $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function run()
    {
        $this->mockMePlease("var");
    }

    public function mockMePlease($var){}
}

class TclassTest extends \Codeception\Test\Unit
{
    public function testMe()
    {
        $mongoDist = Stub::make(
            '\foo\Tclass',
            array(
                'mockMePlease' => function($var) {
                })
        );
    }
}
```

Executing my unit test I have:

> [TypeError] Argument 1 passed to
>   PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_InvocationMocker::__construct() must be
>   of the type array, object given, called in
>   .../phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/src/Framework/MockObject/Generator.php(345)
>   : eval()'d code on line 54

Any idea to avoid that?

```
Codeception version 2.2.9
PHP 7.0.7 (cli) (built: Sep 20 2016 12:46:45) ( ZTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with DBG v8.2.4, (C) 2000,2016, by Dmitri Dmitrienko
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
[*] pthreads     3.1.7dev
```

Comment: checkout this : [ThreadedTest.php](https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads-polyfill/blob/master/tests/ThreadedTest.php)

Comment: Tnx What you mean? I have to do something like $mongoDist = Stub::make(  '\foo\Tclass' ); $mongoDist->mockMePlease = function($var){};??

Answer (score 1):

It is not going to work. From the [docs](https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads):

> array coerced to Volatile when set as member of Threaded

which makes any derivative of `\Threaded` not compatible with PHPUnit mocks.

The framework uses `array` type hinting parameter of [InvocationMocker::__construct](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-mock-objects/blob/master/src/InvocationMocker.php#L38), which is being called from within the mocked class, using private array of mocked methods as a parameter.

Since the mock inherits from the mocked class, and so `\Threaded`, all private arrays are actually `Volatile` objects.

In simple words, following code fails with the same error:

```
class A extends Threaded
{
    private $a = [1,2,3];

    public function run()
    {
        return $this->runArray($this->a);
    }

    public function runArray(array $v)
    {
        return $v;
    }
}

var_dump((new A)->runArray([1,2,3]));  // works. array is outside of \Threaded
var_dump((new A)->run());              // TypeError - A::$a is an object.
```

Comment: So also method of threaded object are stored as a Volatile member

Comment: How come? Methods are not arrays, aren't they?